# loop many combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function, for-loop, combobox

I am creating a GPA calculator with 10 combo boxes (`CmbGrade1, CmbGrade2, CmbGrade3,...,CmbGrade10`)  to select grade points and 10 text boxes(`textbox1,textbox2,textbox3,...,textbox10`) to enter credits and i have created a function to apply it to each combo boxes 
as i have to multiply `textbox.text` with the `CmbGrade.selecteditem` next to it.

I'm using a for loop to call this funtion for ten combo boxes 
so please guide me to loop the combo boxes

```
Public Function Gpa(ByVal grade As Single, ByVal credit As Single)
    Return grade * credit
End Function
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Before you start asking such questions, you need to research what a [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx) is -  yours has no return type.

Comment: @TheBlueDog, in `VB.NET` if `Option strict = Off`. Function without Return type will return Object type by default or try to decide it type

Comment: @Fabio: Who _doesn't_ set `Option Strict On`? Oh, wait ...

Comment: @clweeks there's not an error i just want the code to loop the combo boxes with this function

Comment: Tried to improve formatting

Answer (score 0):

AS the blue dog mentioned in the comment your function should return a value. you can use this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13372/Functions-VS-Subroutines-and-By-Val-Vs-By-Ref-in-V) if you are unaware about the  difference between `Function and Sub`. now you can use the following code to loop through the the controls inside the form control. hope that it will help you.

Consider the following two methods:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To 2
        Dim combo As ComboBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("CmbGrade" & i, True)(0), ComboBox)
        Dim txtBox As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i, True)(0), TextBox)
        Dim x = Gpa(CSng(combo.SelectedItem), CSng(txtBox.Text))
    Next
End Sub

Public Function Gpa(ByVal grade As Single, ByVal credit As Single) As Single
    Return grade * credit
End Function
```